# SQL Server database Log file size larger

Tags: sql-server

I have database in SQL Server, when I create backup the size of backup file is 4 Gb and its data log file shows 136 GB. When I restore the log file size shows 136GB which effect over performance - is there any solution?

Thank you in advance

I googled but did not find solution.

Comment: FWIW, this is unlikely the cause of your performance problems.

Answer (score -1):

it's generally okay to shrink the transaction log file after taking a full and log backup if it has grown excessively. However, be cautious when shrinking as it can cause fragmentation. It's essential to monitor your database's size regularly and follow best practices to avoid log file growth.

[you can see here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/239778/sql-server-shrink-log-after-full-and-log-backup)

Comment: you can Check Recovery Model or Avoid Long Transactions

Comment: thank you for your quick response ,I executed below command its reduced size to very low and my database is also working, I hope I did not lost my data .

ALTER DATABASE DatabaseName
SET RECOVERY SIMPLE
GO
DBCC SHRINKFILE (log name, 1)
GO
ALTER DATABASE log name
SET RECOVERY FULL